# Link rendering bug in answer on the Stack Overflow site

Tags: bug, status-completed

When I view [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256/equation-expression-parser-with-precedence/29124#29124), the link for "recursive descent parser" from the first line also gets applied to the next few paragraphs.

I thought the poster had made a mistake, so I clicked on "edit". In that mode, the preview is correct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like there was a markdown processing bug but it was fixed. When posts are created/edited they're rendered once and saved, so they don't need to be rerendered every time somebody looks at them. Since that post hadn't been edited since 2009, it was still using a rendering from 2009. I made a trivial edit just now and it rerendered the whole post, which fixed the link

Comment: Thanks - knowing that a simple edit can fix older posts is handy.